# Consolidating 2 queries with an INNER JOIN and Get a calculated column from them

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

First off, I am working in Access 2007.

I have two queries that both aggregates by date.

The first one returns an aggregated daily weighted return

```
SELECT Records.RecDate, Sum([YTD]*[Weight]) AS UnadjReturn
FROM Records
WHERE (((Records.[Class1])="eq") AND ((Records.[Class2])="ce"))
GROUP BY Records.RecDate;
```

Result:

```
RecDate UnadjReturn
11/27/2012  0.060778036742704
12/11/2012  0.075592752895318
12/14/2012  7.47574641136453E-02
```

I also have another query that returns daily total class portfolio weight by summing the weight of all the assets in an asset class with respect to the entire portfolio:

```
SELECT Records.RecDate, Sum(Records.Weight) AS SumOfWeight
FROM Records
WHERE (((Records.[Class1])="eq") AND ((Records.[Class2])="ce"))
GROUP BY Records.RecDate;
```

which returns:

```
RecDate SumOfWeight
11/27/2012  0.479327081236988
12/11/2012  0.483075813390315
12/14/2012  0.482791727874428
```

Now I would like to write a consolidated query that multiplies each day's `UnadjReturn` by `SumOfWeight`. I have tried `INNER JOIN` the two and then multiply the two variables as follows,

```
SELECT joined.RecDate, joined.UnadjReturn * joined.SumOfWeight as AdjReturn
FROM joined
(
SELECT Records.RecDate, Sum([YTD]*[Weight]) AS UnadjReturn
FROM Records
WHERE (((Records.[Class1])="eq") AND ((Records.[Class2])="ce"))
GROUP BY Records.RecDate
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Records.RecDate, Sum(Records.Weight) AS SumOfWeight
FROM Records
WHERE (((Records.[Class1])="eq") AND ((Records.[Class2])="ce"))
GROUP BY Records.RecDate;
) t2
ON Records.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AS joined
)
```

This is not looking good at all. Any suggestions? I could do it by querying the two queries with another query, but I would like to take care of it in just one.

Comment: What is wrong with the query you have above? (Other than it's not looking good...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use each of your 2 existing queries as subqueries and `INNER JOIN` them together.  (Make sure to discard the semi-colon from the end of each `SELECT` statement first.)

```sql
SELECT
    sub1.RecDate,
    (sub1.UnadjReturn * sub2.SumOfWeight) AS AdjReturn
FROM
    (
        SELECT Records.RecDate, Sum([YTD]*[Weight]) AS UnadjReturn
        FROM Records
        WHERE Records.[Class1]="eq" AND Records.[Class2]="ce"
        GROUP BY Records.RecDate
    ) AS sub1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Records.RecDate, Sum(Records.Weight) AS SumOfWeight
        FROM Records
        WHERE Records.[Class1]="eq" AND Records.[Class2]="ce"
        GROUP BY Records.RecDate
    ) AS sub2
    ON sub1.RecDate = sub2.RecDate;
```

Comment: Isn't that what the OP has in the query at the bottom of the post (other than different aliases)?

Comment: @Andrew No, the Access SQL in the question is not valid.

Comment: This is it. Looks like naming both queries is the way to go.

Comment: It looked to me like your question's SQL attempted to fold both those subqueries into another subquery named `joined`.  Although that is possible, I don't see an advantage.  However, going that route would require valid syntax ... and this pattern is not valid: `FROM joined (subqueries) AS joined`  Instead, you would have to do `FROM (subqueries) AS joined`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Access, but are you ultimately just looking for the product of the sums or is there some requirement (Access-based or class project or???) that you need to use subqueries.

Here's a SQL Server answer...

```
SELECT
    RecDate,
    (Sum([YTD]*[Weight]) * Sum(Records.Weight)) AS AdjReturn
FROM Records
        WHERE Records.[Class1]='eq' AND Records.[Class2]='ce'
        GROUP BY Records.RecDate
```